# Как сократить время выполнения запроса в mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

У меня есть коллекция с Counts в которой порядка 2 миллионов записей и с каждым днем она растет и растет. Эта коллекция содержит записи по просмотрам некоторых страниц включая время просмотра.

```
{
 _id: _id,
 href: { type: String },
 count: { type: Number, default: 1 },
 createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
}
```

Мне нужно выбрать последние записи за 30 дней и суммировать поле count.
Для этого я делаю запрос следующего вида

```
return Counts.aggregate([
        {
            $match: { createdAt: { $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 30 )) } }
        }, {
            $project: {
                _id: 1,
                href: 1,
                count: 1
            }
        }, {
            $group: {
                _id: "$href",
                count: {
                    $sum: "$count"
                }
            }
        }, {
            $sort: { count: -1 }
        }, {
            $skip: 0
        }, {
            $limit: 12
        }
    ])
```

Проблема в том что такой запрос выполняется примерно 10 секунд и всего скорее время будет расти по мере появления новых документов в коллекции Counts

Что можно сделать? Быть может как то перестроить саму коллекцию или же сам запрос?
Индексы созданы для следующих полей

```
db.counts.createIndex({ href: 1 })
db.counts.createIndex({ count: 1 })
db.counts.createIndex({ createdAt: 1 })
```

Но не думаю что проблема с индексами, всего скорее проблема в объеме базы данных.

Comment: 1) Не пробовали определить, какой именно этап самою большую задержку дает: выборка, группировка? 2) Может быть, если дату перевести в миллисекунды, и в дальнейшем работать с числом - выборка будет быстрее?

Comment: 1. Убрал все лишнее, оставил только project, условие такое же, не старше 30 последних дней, запрос долгий, а именно 16 сек.  2. Попробовал, изменил более миллиона записей, результат такой же.

Comment: Запрос 
    db.counts.count({ createdAt: { $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 30 )) } }) 
находит 1834057
выполняется очень быстро

Comment: Без условия работает в два раза быстрее, 5 секунд, но данные будут совсем не те, не понимаю в чем проблема, по получается дело именно в выборке, с группировкой запрос работает даже быстрее чем без него, забавно

Comment: создал тестовую коллекцию с 2 млн. записей. Дата в ней записана в миллесекундах, вариантов ссылок - 7шт.  Ваш запрос отработал за 4 секунды. Время на подключение к БД не учитывал.

Comment: У меня вариантов ссылок порядка 200-400, но даже 4 секунды это много, сейчас у меня выполняется порядка 7-8сек запрос. Долго.... хоть и кеширую результаты, но приходится раз в сутки скидывать кеш и сидишь ждешь когда страница отобразится =(

Comment: выборка проходила без индекса. Можете дать код, формирующий соотвествующую базу?

Comment: Пользователи формируют базу, там ничего такого нет, обычное сохранение вот такого объекта new Counts({ href: "james-rodriguez-real-madrid", count: 6 }).save(), ну и естественно значение по умолчанию в схеме подстегивается createdAt

Comment: То понятно. Но для тестов, если кто-то захочет помочь, было бы неплохо, если бы в вопросе был код формирующий соответствующую базу

Comment: Я не разу не создавал такой объем данных сразу, я не в курсе как такое делать чтобы комп не сдох =)

Comment: 4 сек - это много? А какой Вы результат хотите?

Comment: Мои хотелки макс 1сек) Я кое что другое придумал, по крону делать подсчет и обновлять основной документ, так выборка будет от 10-20 миллисекунд